# Can we define the concept of temperature for a system in non-equilibrium steady state?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium

I would like to define the temperature for a system in a non-equilibrium steady-state. The standard textbooks show that the temperature is estimated by equating the internal energy of the system with the thermal energy (equipartition theorem). But I am sceptical to use it for the system in steady-state. Any thoughts on this topic are highly appreciable?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319209/how-is-temperature-defined-in-non-equilibrium

Comment: @PeaBrane Thanks, Got it!